# Upgrade Windows 8.1 to 10

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

After downloading Windows 10 it won't install, says I have error 80070005 which is DCOM authentication error.

I have checked all my DCOMCNFG access & network permissions & ticked everything but no luck. I even ran that small program from technet microsoft forum beginning Set OSBIT=32 and ran as administrator but still no luck.

I have an Asus laptop with a removable touch screen tablet containing android.
Can anyone help please as I have to download this massive 2.84 gig program each time I try.

Answer (score -1):

From [Ten Forums](http://www.tenforums.com/installation-setup/9732-windows-10-couldnt-installed-error-code-80070005-a.html) :

> **Description**
>
> The error occurs when you attempt to install Windows updates. When you
>   try to click on check for updates in Windows Update with administrator
>   privileges you cannot install updates and instead you receive error
>   code 80070005.
>
> **Step-by-step instruction**
>
> Error code 80070005 is caused by a number of factors some of which
>   include an error in the **DCOM** configuration or the Automatic Updates
>   service. You can begin to solve the problem by seeking verification
>   for the **DCOM** configuration. To do this simply click on Start on your
>   main toolbar on the desktop and then choose Run from the pop-up menu.
>   When the Command Prompt appears type in dcomcnfg and then press the
>   Enterkey. When the Component Services window opens double click on the
>   Component Services folder and then double click on the Computers
>   folder. Right click on My Computer and then choose Properties from the
>   drop down menu. When the Properties window opens click on the COM
>   Security tab and then click on Edit Default and then check to see that
>   the correct accounts are listed
>
> In the event that one of your accounts is missing you can simply click
>   on Add and then choose Advanced. Click on Locations and then choose
>   Local Computer Name and then choose OK. Proceed to click on Find Now
>   and then press down the CTRL key on your keyboard. Choose the correct
>   Account Names and click OK twice.Under User Names choose the account
>   that you added and then choose Local Access in the Permissions area
>   and then place a check mark in the Allow column and then click OK.
>
> Once you complete this process it is necessary to confirm the default
>   settings for DCOM. You can do this by choosing the Default
>   Propertiestab and make sure Enable Distributed COM has a check mark
>   placed inside the selection box,Identifyis checked under Default
>   Impersonation, and Connect has a check mark under Default
>   Authentication and then click OK. Restart your computer when you have
>   completed this process.
>   Also try out the Microsoft [solution](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/968003)

Comment: I have already done all this as I said in my original post but the error still occurs after download and a lengthy "Preparing to Install"